# Safari iOS | 100%-height page too high for viewport

Tags: ios, css, ipad, safari, height

I've got a problem with a simple webpage. It isn't quite finished but I tried this one with my iPad in Safari and there appeared a vertical scrollbar altough the document shouldn't be higher than the viewport. (only in landscape mode)

In Chrome for iOS and the desktop version (1367x768px) it's running nearly perfect & I don't understand why there's a problem in safari.

This phenomen is only appearing in Safari/iOS/landscape.
Hope it's more or less comprehensible.

Thanks a lot!

Felix

Answer (score 0):

The following style is for the `body` tag and not the `html` tag:

`height: 100%;`

So, remove this style from `html, body { height: 100%; ... }` and this should solve the issue. Infact you can remove `html` from that block. It won't affect the output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the scrollbar appears in spite of the change.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is solved in Safari for iOS 8.